# defaultConfig, buildTypes, packagingOptions and dependencies cannot be applied to (groovy.lang.Closure)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I know this question was answer before but non of the them worked for me. The app compiles and run perfectly but this warning it's annoying. Basicly defaultConfig, buildTypes, packagingOptions and dependencies in mobile gradle, and dependencies in top level gradle all give the cannot be applied to (groovy.lang.Closure) warning:

Top level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

mobile gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.udazz.udazz"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, updating to gradle 1.3.1 worked for me.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'`